# How to get strings between `[ and `] in lua?

Tags: neovim, mark, vimscript-lua

I'm trying to play around with text objects in lua, here's what I got:

https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/33.html

On that webpage, I found that I can operate on the text send to motion function via

`` `[v\`]y ``(for charwise motion) or `` `<v`>y ``(for visual motion), then they go to the registers

However, I don't want to yank them to the register, so is there some work around?

Comment: What do you mean by "mess up the register"? And what _exactly_ do you want to do with the target text? Details increase your odds of getting quality answers.

Comment: By messing up I mean I don't want them to yank to the register, I've updated it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me put things another way. You shouldn't expect people to follow links to figure out what exactly you want to do. Provide all the details here. Besides explaining why you want to avoid registers, what exactly  is your operatorfunc supposed to do? "Get strings...in lua" ...I'm not sure what that means.